# What to do to make sure admob is ready to go to production?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, admob

I'm integrated admob with my ios game and everything works great.

I can't find a "switch" option from test to production just like I have in other ad networks (vungle for example).

I can find zero information how to prepare it to be published (maybe it is too obvious?).

That makes me very uncomfortable, because I want to make sure the ads will be real ones and I will get paid for that.

for example, should I remove my device id from request testing property?

should I not worried because admob is smart enough to figure out if it is production or testing?

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ads are already live. They provide the test devices dictionary so that it can detect its a test ad. If you ran the app on a device which isnt in the test devices dictionary, you will receive live ads. Obviously AdMob will block your service if you purposefully make real requests from development.

I accidentally ran an app on a device that wasnt in the test devices and I got a real advert. I'm sure it happens often so they probably excuse a certain amount of accidental real requests.

Answer (score 1):

> for example, should I remove my device id from request testing property?

Yes, you should remove your Test ID in your distribution release. Only use the Ad Unit ID given to you by AdMob to request ads in your distribution release.

> I can't find a "switch" option from test to production just like I have in other ad networks (vungle for example).

There is no *switch* for you to turn on when you plan to build your application for distribution. If you're successfully receiving test ads on your device then you've implemented the advertisements correctly.

> That makes me very uncomfortable, because I want to make sure the ads will be real ones and I will get paid for that.

You can receive live ads before the release of your application in the App Store by removing your Test ID and running your application on a real device.